# Solutions of mapping JSON data to objective-c data model class?

Tags: ios, json, parsing, persistence

Server side usually provides JSON data response for different clients, such as browser, iOS client app, android client app etc.

At the client side, some parser will be used to convert such JSON data to specific data model classes defined by Objective-C or Java etc (depending on language or device clients ).

Do we really need to do the conversion between JSON data and data model class ? Or solution to just make full usage of JSON ( persisting JSON data, consuming JSON data ? )

Or if we really need do something like conversion, any good practice ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the easiest way to map the JSON data with a data model/object.

Have a look at [RestKit](http://restkit.org/):

> RestKit is an Objective-C framework for iOS that aims to make interacting with RESTful web services simple, fast and fun. It combines a clean, simple HTTP request/response API with a powerful object mapping system that reduces the amount of code you need to write to get stuff done.

in my opinion it is the best and easiest way to deal with JSON/XML restful webservices. You can easily map JSON to object or even directly to managedobjects in core data.

Comment: Yes,RestKit does some object mapping, but I do not think it is too simple and easy to use. Personally I prefer there is one tiny project to just do the mapping stuff from JSON to object model. Thanks anyway.